# Why can Google not direct me to the paper?

Tags: search-engine

I enter this reference into the google search field

Nature 2008 May 8;453(7192):164-6

I expect at least one link to be from the nature.com website, I mean it says "Nature" in the query. All results are from ncbi, which only collects abstracts. Is that so hard? Usually references in journals are in such or a similar format... How come it's not recognized as such?
Please redirect the question to the appropriate stackexchange sub-field if necessary.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

When Google lists query results, it takes into consideration website popularity. Your paper is both on ncbi and nature.com and because nsbi website is ranked at 361-st and nature.com is at 2,984-th for internet traffic from alexa.com, your Google results will be like that.

Comment: Good input. But it can't be the end of the story. I checked for a couple of different examples (Nature Biotechnology 2005, 23, 1294–1301), where it perfectly lists the link to the journal, which is what I want.

Comment: You asked "why", so I provided a reason why.